# Could not get unknown property 'okhttpVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, retrofit, build.gradle

Following dependencies are added inside `build.gradle` file for Implementing **Retrofit API** Call in My new **Kotlin** Project.

```
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"){
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
```

After Syncing it will show an error mentioned below.

```
Could not get unknown property 'okhttpVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

studio pointing error line is,

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
```

please give any Solution for it.

Comment: how `okhttpVersion` is defined/set?

Comment: @Nik please do not change code tag to quote for error logs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define version value like

```
def okhttpVersion = "3.10.0"
def retrofitVersion = "2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"){
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
```

**OR** try to add hardcoded version of dependencies

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0"
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"){
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
```

don't forget to clean and rebuild...

Comment: oh,,,,thanks Omi,,,version number missed,,its really my mistake.

Comment: if this help to resolve your problem then upvote and mark this as accept answer like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376420

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution if someone is interested.

If you are able to find out what the version number is, you can define the `okhttpVersion` in the project build.gradle file.

My version was `room_version` instead of `version_room`. This was also an easy fix.

[image]